# What would the H di baryon wave function which is an isospin singlet be?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

I realise that the baryon octet forms a 8 dim irrep of SU(3). What would would the H di baryon wave function be? Specifically, I am looking for an irrep with I=0 and S=-2, having the quark content of $udsuds$.

Comment: The $\Lambda^0$ is already an iso-spin singlet, so the iso-spin wave functions is just $\Lambda\Lambda$. You can make it a spin singlet to get the right overall symmetry. (The whole thing is called the H di-baryon).

Comment: @Thomas There are many other combinations that yield an isospin singlet. For example consider the combination $\Sigma^+ \Sigma^- +\Sigma^- \Sigma^+ -\Sigma^0 \Sigma^0$. This is also an isospin singlet with the same quark content. These states,$\Lambda \Lambda$ or the state I mentioned cannot form a basis for an irrep.

Comment: [This link](http://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/pram/061/05/1009-1013) writes down a wave function without a clear explanation as to how it was obtained. Any help?

Comment: All of these wave functions are perfectly good isospin singlets. What you are asking is something different: Which linear combination of these wave functions is an eigenstate of the QCD Hamiltonian?  That is not a group theory question, you would actually have to solve QCD.